# SPF issue You're not fully authenticated

Tags: spf

I just setup my own mail server and it works fine. However, I wanted to set it up right.

[image: SPF report]

After spending countless hours of adding different txt files had no luck. What I understand is, I just add txt record `v=spf1 a mx ip4:94.177.216.63 ~all` to the psrp subdomain.

What should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've done this wrong. Your center-link.com SPF is:

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:94.177.216.63 include:psrp.center-link.com  include:services.center-link.com redirect=_spf.yandex.net ?all
```

but `psrp.center-link.com` does not have an SPF to include, and nor does `services`, so they do nothing. Change your main SPF record to this:

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:94.177.216.63 redirect=_spf.yandex.net ~all
```

Then add two SPF records for the `psrp` and `services` subdomains that just include your main SPF:

```
v=spf1 include:center-link.com ~all
```

You'll also see I've changed the default action to `~all`; `?all` is equivalent to not having an SPF record at all, so it's pointless.

Check your config using [Scott Kitterman's validator](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html).